# Javascript - deepEqual Comparison

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, comparison, equality

Question (From Eloquent Javascript 2nd Edition, Chapter 4, Exercise 4):

> Write a function, deepEqual, that takes two values and returns true only if they
>       are the same value or are objects with the same properties whose values are also
>       equal when compared with a recursive call to deepEqual.

Test Cases:

```
var obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj));
// → true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: 1, object: 2}));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}));
// → true
```

My code:

```
var deepEqual = function (x, y) {
  if ((typeof x == "object" && x != null) && (typeof y == "object" && y != null)) {
    if (Object.keys(x).length != Object.keys(y).length)
      return false;
    for (var prop in x) {
      if (y.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        return deepEqual(x[prop], y[prop]);
    /*This is most likely where my error is. The question states that all the values
    should be checked via recursion; however, with the current setup, only the first
    set of properties will be checked. It passes the test cases, but I would like
    to solve the problem correctly!*/
      }
    }
  else if (x !== y)
    return false;
  else
    return true;
}
```

I think I have the general idea down; however, like I stated in the comment, the program will not check the second property in the objects. I feel like I have a structural/logic problem and am simply using recursion in the wrong way, as I originally intended to loop through the properties, use recursion to compare the values of the first property, then continue on in the loop to the next property and compare again.  Although, I'm not sure if that's even possible?

I've given a good amount of thought and tried a couple different approaches, but this was the most correct answer I've come to so far.  Any possible tips to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As you suspect, you're returning the match of the first property seen.  You should return `false` if that property doesn't match, but keep looking otherwise.

Also, return `false` if there's no `prop` property found on `y` (that is, the counts match, but not the actual properties).

If all properties have matched, return `true`:

```
var deepEqual = function (x, y) {
  if (x === y) {
    return true;
  }
  else if ((typeof x == "object" && x != null) && (typeof y == "object" && y != null)) {
    if (Object.keys(x).length != Object.keys(y).length)
      return false;

    for (var prop in x) {
      if (y.hasOwnProperty(prop))
      {  
        if (! deepEqual(x[prop], y[prop]))
          return false;
      }
      else
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
  }
  else 
    return false;
}
```

```js
var deepEqual = function (x, y) {
  if (x === y) {
    return true;
  }
  else if ((typeof x == "object" && x != null) && (typeof y == "object" && y != null)) {
    if (Object.keys(x).length != Object.keys(y).length)
      return false;

    for (var prop in x) {
      if (y.hasOwnProperty(prop))
      {  
        if (! deepEqual(x[prop], y[prop]))
          return false;
      }
      else
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
  else 
    return false;
}

var obj = {here: {is: "an", other: "3"}, object: 2};
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj));
// → true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: 1, object: 2}));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an", other: "2"}, object: 2}));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an", other: "3"}, object: 2}));
// → true
```

Comment: It'd probably also be a good idea to do a `.hasOwnProperty()` check on the property of "x", or, better, use the return values already obtained by the calls to `Object.keys()` to do the iteration, since those will already be limited to "own" properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm still new to recursion, but your changes illustrate a good lesson on the topic. I had an idea why my code didn't work, and your solution is straightforward. Thanks again, and enjoy the upvote!

Comment: why not have if(x === y) at the top of the function? that way, if that returns true, it saves having to go through the first large if block

Comment: Definitely worth trying (and profiling, to see if it actually makes a difference). In this case, I was trying to stay as close as possible to the question's structure, to make the differences clear.

Comment: Well, I think it may cause stack overflow exception if the object is circular, e.g `var a = {foo: 3}; a.bar = a; deepEqual(a, a);`

Comment: @Stephen.W You're right. I've adjusted the code accordingly.

Comment: Just a heads up: this may give false positives if you don't stick to JSON serializable objects. i.e.; any two RegExps will be evaluated as being the same. deepEqual(/a/, /b/) => true

Comment: Replacing the null and x == "object" checks for a more explicit check of x.constructor === Object || Array.isArray(x) seems to fix the aforementioned problem.

Comment: can someone explain how this program checks for array of integers?

Comment: @kharish The object comparison handles that. Think of an array as an object whose keys are `0, 1, 2...`. The `for... in` loops through those "keys" and compares the values (in this case, the integers in the array). There's no need - and no sensible way - to treat arrays differently. Example: https://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/NWxvprK?editors=0011

Comment: There are a few problems with this answer. 1) The question asks about [same-value equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#same-value_equality), but this answer uses strict equality. 2) This function is not always symmetrical; in some cases, `deepEqual(a, b) !== deepEqual(b, a)`. 3) The function will throw an error if `y` does not inherit from `Object` (e.g. if it is created using `Object.create(null)`. I believe my answer solves all of these.

Answer (score 21):

Feel that this version is a bit more readable (easier to comprehend). The logic is very similar with the top answer though. (ES6 this time)

```js
function deepEqual(obj1, obj2) {

    if(obj1 === obj2) // it's just the same object. No need to compare.
        return true;

    if(isPrimitive(obj1) && isPrimitive(obj2)) // compare primitives
        return obj1 === obj2;

    if(Object.keys(obj1).length !== Object.keys(obj2).length)
        return false;

    // compare objects with same number of keys
    for(let key in obj1)
    {
        if(!(key in obj2)) return false; //other object doesn't have this prop
        if(!deepEqual(obj1[key], obj2[key])) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

//check if value is primitive
function isPrimitive(obj)
{
    return (obj !== Object(obj));
}
```

By the way, there is a **cheater version** of deep equal which works like a charm)) However, it's approximately 1.6 times slower.

**As noticed by zero298, this approach is sensitive to the properties ordering and shouldn't be taken seriously**

```
function cheatDeepEqual(obj1, obj2)
{
    return JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2);
}
```

Comment: I think the "cheater" version may fail if property order is not the same.  Consider this example tested in node.js: `JSON.stringify({foo:"bar",fizz:"buzz"}) === JSON.stringify({fizz:"buzz", foo:"bar"});` is false; but `JSON.stringify({foo:"bar",fizz:"buzz"}) === JSON.stringify({foo:"bar",fizz:"buzz"});` is true.

Comment: @zero298, yeah, I guess you're right. Anyhow this approach shouldn't be taken too seriously :)

Comment: Also when you do JSON.stringify and convert back using parse and if there are any date objects it will be converted to a string type FYI

Comment: Object.keys needs null check

Comment: fails for `deepEqual([],{})`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variable outside the for loop to keep track of the comparison:

```
var allPropertiesEqual = true;
for (var prop in x) {
    if (y.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        allPropertiesEqual = deepEqual(x[prop], y[prop]) && allPropertiesEqual;
    } else {
        allPropertiesEqual = false;
    }
}
return allPropertiesEqual;
```

The previous example is not optimized on purpose. Because you're comparing objects, you know that you can `return false` as soon as you find an inequality, and you can keep looping while all the previous checked properties are equal:

```
for (var prop in x) {
    if (y.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        if (! deepEqual(x[prop], y[prop]) )
            return false; //first inequality found, return false
    } else {
        return false; //different properties, so inequality, so return false
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: This will return true for `{ a: 1, b: 2 }` compared to `{ c : 3, d: 4 }`, since `hasOwnProperty()` will always be false and all the tests will be skipped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wish that I could give a green check to both of you, as you both have good, detailed answers. :( I still gave you an upvote though!

Answer (score 2):

I am quite new to JS but this is the way I solved it:

```
function deepEqual(obj1, obj2) {
if (typeof obj1 === "object" && typeof obj2 === "object") {
    let isObjectMatch = false;
    for (let property1 in obj1) {
        let isPropertyMatch = false;
        for (let property2 in obj2) {
            if (property1 === property2) {
                isPropertyMatch = deepEqual(obj1[property1], obj2[property2])
            }

            if(isPropertyMatch){
                break;
            }
        }

        isObjectMatch  = isPropertyMatch;

        if (!isObjectMatch) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return isObjectMatch;
} else {
    return obj1 === obj2;
}
}
```

And here are my tests:

```
var obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj));
// → true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: 1, object: 2}));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}))
// → true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {object: 2, here: {is: "an"}}));
// → true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {object: 1, here: {is: "an"}}));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {objectt: 2, here: {is: "an"}}));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(2, 2));
// → true
console.log(deepEqual(2, 3));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(2, null));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(null, null));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, null));
// → false
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the accepted answer by Paul Roub, I needed it to also match function values, and I wanted it to be a lot more concise, so I've refactored it.

```js
function deepEqual(x, y, z) {
  return x === y || typeof x == "function" && y && x.toString() == y.toString()
    || x && y && typeof x == "object" && x.constructor == y.constructor
    && (z = Object.keys(y)) && z.length == Object.keys(x).length
    && !z.find(v => !deepEqual(x[v], y[v]));
}

var myFunc = (x) => { return x*2; }
var obj = {here: {is: "an", other: "3"}, object: 2, andFunc: myFunc};
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj));
// → true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: 1, object: 2, andFunc: myFunc}));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2, andFunc: myFunc}));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an", other: "2"}, object: 2, andFunc: myFunc}));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an", other: "3"}, object: 2, andFunc: myFunc}));
// → true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an", other: "3"}, object: 2, andFunc: (x) => { return x*2; }}));
// → true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an", other: "3"}, object: 2, andFunc: (x) => { return x*999; }}));
// → false
```

notes:

- You pass in only 2 args: x and y (z is for internal use).
- If one of the variables is `null` or `undefined` it returns that value instead of `false`, but that result is still "falsey" so I'm OK with it.  To fix that you could change all occurrences of `y &&` to `(y || !1) &&` and `x &&` to `(x || !1) &&`
- If you definitely don't expect that functions/callbacks would be supplied in
  your objects then remove `|| typeof x == "function" && y && x.toString() == y.toString()`

Comment: Comparing functions based on how they print is *wrong*.  Try this:
```js
const plus = x => y => x + y;
deepEqual(plus(1), plus(2))
```

Answer (score 2):

All of the previous answers contain subtle errors that will cause them to fail in certain cases. They all either 1) depend on properties being in the same order or 2) return asymmetrical results in some cases, so that `deepEqual(a, b) !== deepEqual(b, a)`. Here is an improved answer, assuming the following:

- We are interested in [same-value equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#same-value_equality); we want `deepEqual(NaN, NaN)` to return `true`, but `deepEqual(0, -0)` to return `false`.
- We only care about enumerable, string-keyed properties defined directly on our objects (i.e., those properties returned by [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)).
- Full support for circular references is not needed.

```js
/**
 * Tests whether two values are deeply equal using same-value equality.
 *
 * Two values are considered deeply equal iff 1) they are the same value, or
 * 2) they are both non-callable objects whose own, enumerable, string-keyed
 * properties are deeply equal.
 *
 * Caution: This function does not fully support circular references. Use this
 * function only if you are sure that at least one of the arguments has no
 * circular references.
 */
function deepEqual(x, y) {
    // If either x or y is not an object, then they are deeply equal iff they
    // are the same value. For our purposes, objects exclude functions,
    // primitive values, null, and undefined.
    if (typeof x !== "object" || x === null ||
        typeof y !== "object" || y === null) {
        // We use Object.is() to check for same-value equality. To check for
        // strict equality, we would use x === y instead.
        return Object.is(x, y);
    }

    // Shortcut, in case x and y are the same object. Every object is
    // deeply equal to itself.
    if (x === y)
        return true;

    // Obtain the own, enumerable, string-keyed properties of x. We ignore
    // properties defined along x's prototype chain, non-enumerable properties,
    // and properties whose keys are symbols.
    const keys = Object.keys(x);
    // If x and y have a different number of properties, then they are not
    // deeply equal.
    if (Object.keys(y).length !== keys.length)
        return false;

    // For each own, enumerable, string property key of x:
    for (const key of keys) {
        // If key is not also an own enumerable property of y, or if x[key] and
        // y[key] are not themselves deeply equal, then x and y are not deeply
        // equal. Note that we don't just call y.propertyIsEnumerable(),
        // because y might not have such a method (for example, if it was
        // created using Object.create(null)), or it might not be the same
        // method that exists on Object.prototype.
        if (!Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable.call(y, key) ||
            !deepEqual(x[key], y[key])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // x and y have the same properties, and all of those properties are deeply
    // equal, so x and y are deeply equal.
    return true;
}
```

Comment: fails for `deepEqual([],{})`

Comment: @hannadrehman It returns `true` for `deepEqual([], {})`, which is correct according to the doc comment: they're both non-callable objects with zero own, enumerable, string-keyed properties. But for a lot of applications (e.g., comparing JSON structures), you may want to distinguish between an empty object and an empty array, in which case you would need to make sure that both arguments are either arrays or non-array objects. But there's no `deepEqual()` function that will work for all applications, because how you define deep equality depends on the use case.

Comment: i m not really sure if thats correct. extending to my problem `deepEqual({x:[]},{x:{}})` should not be equal. but according to this function it is. @McMath

Comment: @hannadrehman `deepEqual({x:[]},{x:{}})` correctly returns `true` according to the definition in the doc comment, which doesn't distinguish at all between arrays and plain objects. There are even stranger examples: `deepEqual([10], {0: 10})` returns `true`; so does `deepEqual(new Set(), new Date())`. The problem is that this definition of deep equality doesn't make sense in your use case (and probably most use cases, for that matter). There is no definition of deep equality that will make sense in every application. I'll add this caveat to my answer.

Comment: this is quite interesting. we need to follow some standard  here other wise it may lead to unwanted bugs. i checked how nodes `assert` module handles this case https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assertdeepequalactual-expected-message. it is handled properly there. all of cases give expected results when using `assert.deepEqual()`

Comment: @hannadrehman Yes, [Node's implementation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/74b9baa4265a8f0d112dabc3efc63c2e13276488/lib/internal/util/comparisons.js) has strict type checking and fully supports circular references; it's also more than 500 lines of code. If all you need is to distinguish arrays from plain objects, [here is a modified version of this function](https://gist.github.com/mcmath/98e52fc708d5fd7fee46265943c53573) that may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Although that it's more verbose, maybe this option is easier to read:

```
function deepEqual(elem1, elem2) {
    if(elem1 === elem2) {
        return true;
    }
    if(typeof elem1 == 'object' && typeof elem2 == 'object' && elem1 != null && elem2 != null) {
      if(Object.keys(elem1).length == Object.keys(elem2).length) {
          for(let key of Object.keys(elem1)) {
              if(elem2.hasOwnProperty(key) != true) {
                  return false;
              }
          }
          for(let key of Object.keys(elem1)) {
              if(typeof elem1[key] == 'object' && typeof elem2[key] == 'object' && typeof elem1[key] != null && typeof elem2[key] != null) {
                  return deepEqual(elem1[key], elem2[key]);
              }
              else {
                if(elem1[key] !== elem2[key]) {
                    return false;
                }
              }
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
var cmp = function(element, target){

   if(typeof element !== typeof target)
   {
      return false;
   }
   else if(typeof element === "object" && (!target || !element))
   {
      return target === element;
   }
   else if(typeof element === "object")
   {
       var keys_element = Object.keys(element);
       var keys_target  = Object.keys(target);
       
       if(keys_element.length !== keys_target.length)
       {
           return false;
       }
       else
       {
           for(var i = 0; i < keys_element.length; i++)
           {
                if(keys_element[i] !== keys_target[i])
                    return false;
                if(!cmp(element[keys_element[i]], target[keys_target[i]]))
                    return false;
           }
     return true;
       }
   }
   else
   {
       return element === target;

   }
};

console.log(cmp({
    key1: 3,
    key2: "string",
    key3: [4, "45", {key4: [5, "6", false, null, {v:1}]}]
}, {
    key1: 3,
    key2: "string",
    key3: [4, "45", {key4: [5, "6", false, null, {v:1}]}]
})); // true

console.log(cmp({
    key1: 3,
    key2: "string",
    key3: [4, "45", {key4: [5, "6", false, null, {v:1}]}]
}, {
    key1: 3,
    key2: "string",
    key3: [4, "45", {key4: [5, "6", undefined, null, {v:1}]}]
})); // false
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A simple one:
const isObject = (obj) => {
  return typeof obj === "object" && obj !== null;
};

let isEqual = true;
const deepEqual = (objA, objB) => {
  if (!isEqual) {
    return;
  }
  const keysA = Object.keys(objA);
  const keysB = Object.keys(objB);

  if (keysA.length !== keysB.length) {
    isEqual = false;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < keysA.length; i++) {
    const valA = objA[keysA[i]];
    const valB = objB[keysA[i]];

    if (isObject(valA) && isObject(valB)) {
      deepEqual(valA, valB);
    } else if (valA !== valB) {
      isEqual = false;
    }
  }

  return isEqual;
};
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive version of `deepEquel`:

```
const deeplyEqual = function(obj1, obj2) {
    // if both objects are the same, they're equal
    if (obj1 === obj2) return true;
    // if either object is null, they're not equal
    if (obj1 === null || obj2 === null) return false;
    // if the string representation of both objects are not equal, they're not equal
    if (String(obj1) !== String(obj2)) return false;

    // if the objects are not arrays or objects, they're equal if they're equal
    if (typeof obj1 !== 'object') {
        return obj1 === obj2;
    }

    // if the objects are arrays, they're equal if they have the same length and each element is deeply equal
    if (Array.isArray(obj1)) {
        if (obj1.length !== obj2.length) return false;

        for (let i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++) {
            if (!areDeeplyEqual(obj1[i], obj2[i])) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // if the objects are objects, they're equal if they have the same keys and values are deeply equal
    if (Object.keys(obj1).length !== Object.keys(obj2).length) return false;

    for (const key in obj1) {
        if (!areDeeplyEqual(obj1[key], obj2[key])) return false;
    }

    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the variant below, because:

- Other than the first line checking of `Object.is` equality, every return statement before the end is a "consistent direction", ie. `return false`.
- Can easily derive a `shallowEquals` from it, by setting its `keyCheckLayersLeft` argument to `1`.

Code:

```js
const hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

export function deepEquals(x, y, keyCheckLayersLeft = -1) {
    // fast route: if values are identical, return true
    if (Object.is(x, y)) return true;

    // values are non-identical; so if one is a primitive or null/undefined, they can't be equal, thus return false
    if (typeof x !== "object" || x == null || typeof y !== "object" || y == null) return false;

    // special case (since it's the one "json relevant" object-type): if only one value is an array, consider them non-equal, thus return false
    if (Array.isArray(x) != Array.isArray(y)) return false;

    // values are non-identical objects; so if we've reached the key-check layer-limit, return false
    if (keyCheckLayersLeft == 0) return false;

    // check for differences in the objects' field-names and field-values; if any such difference is found, return false
    // NOTE: Objects.keys() excludes non-enumerable properties; to include them, use Object.getOwnPropertyNames() instead
    const xKeys = Object.keys(x), yKeys = Object.keys(y);
    if (xKeys.length != yKeys.length) return false;
    for (const key of xKeys) {
        if (!hasOwnProperty.call(y, key)) return false;
        if (!deepEquals(x[key], y[key], keyCheckLayersLeft - 1)) return false;
    }

    // none of the checks found a difference, so the objects must be equal
    return true;
}

// because of the keyCheckLayersLeft parameter, we can easily create a shallowEquals function
export function shallowEquals(objA, objB) {
    return deepEquals(objA, objB, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my **typescript** solution which reads better:

```
export const isEqual = <T>(a: T, b: T): boolean => {
  if (a === b) {
    return true;
  }

  const bothAreObjects =
    a && b && typeof a === "object" && typeof b === "object";

  return Boolean(
    bothAreObjects &&
      Object.keys(a).length === Object.keys(b).length &&
      Object.entries(a).every(([k, v]) => isEqual(v, b[k as keyof T]))
  );
};
```

And test coverage:

```
import { isEqual } from "./utils";

const testValues: [unknown, unknown, boolean][] = [
  [null, null, true],
  [undefined, undefined, true],
  [null, undefined, false],
  [undefined, null, false],
  ["undefined", undefined, false],
  ["undefined", "undefined", true],
  [1, 1, true],
  [1, 4, false],
  [3.123, 3.123, true],
  [3.1234567, 3.123, false],
  [false, false, true],
  [true, true, true],
  [true, false, false],
  [false, false, true],
  [[], [], true],
  [[], [1], false],
  [[1], [1], true],
  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, "string"], false],
  [[1, 2, "string"], [1, 3, "string"], false],
  [[1, "2", null, { object: 1 }], [1, "2", null, { object: 1 }], true],
  [[1, 2, { object: 1 }], [1, 2, { object: "string" }], false],
  [{}, {}, true],
  [{}, { test: 1 }, false],
  [{ test: 1 }, {}, false],
  [{ test: 1 }, { test: 1 }, true],
  [{ test: 1 }, { test: 2 }, false],
  [{ test: 1, deep: { test: 2 } }, { test: 1, deep: { test: 2 } }, true],
  [
    { test: 1, deep: { test: "string" } },
    { test: 1, deep: { test: 2 } },
    false,
  ],
];

describe("isEqual", () => {
  test.each(testValues)(
    "Should compare %s and %s (%s)",
    (a, b, expectedResult) => {
      expect(isEqual(a, b)).toEqual(expectedResult);
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I just went through this chapter and wanted to show my work, too.

The flaw in mine (let me know if there are more) is that the object properties have to be in exact order as well. I much prefer @paul and  @danni's solution.

```js
// Deep equal 
const deepEqual = (x, y) => {
  const xType = typeof x;
  const yType = typeof y; 
  
  if ( xType === 'object' && yType === 'object' && ( x !== null && y !== null ) ) {
    const xKeys = Object.keys(x);
    const yKeys = Object.keys(y);
    const xValues = Object.values(x);
    const yValues = Object.values(y);  
    
    // check length of both arrays
    if ( xKeys.length !== yKeys.length ) return false;
    
    // compare keys
    for ( i = 0; i < xKeys.length; i++ )
      if (xKeys[i] !== yKeys[i]) return false;
      
    // compare values
    for ( i = 0; i < xValues.length; i++ )
      if (!deepEqual(xValues[i], yValues[i])) return false;
      
  } else {
    if ( x !== y ) return false;
  }
  return true;
};

// Objects
let obj1 = {
  value: false,
  pets: null
};

let obj2 = {
  value: false,
  pets: null
};


let obj3 = {
  value: false,
  pets: {
    cat: false,
    dog: {
      better: 'yes'
    }
  }
};

let obj4 = {
  value: false,
  pets: { 
    cat: false,
    dog: {
      better: 'yes'
    }
  }
};


let obj5 = {
  value: false,
  dog: true
};

let obj6 = {
  value: false,
  cat: true
};


let obj7 = {
  value: true,
  dog: {
    cat: {
      wow: true
    }
  }
};

let obj8 = {
  value: true,
  dog: {
    cat: {
      wow: false
    }
  }
};


let obj9 = {
  value: true,
  dog: {
    cat: {
      wow: true
    }
  }
};

let obj10 = {
  dog: {
    cat: {
      wow: true
    }
  },
  value: true
};

// Just for building a pretty result, ignore if you'd like
const result = (x, y) => {
  return `For: <br/>
          ${JSON.stringify(x)} <br/>
          and <br/>
          ${JSON.stringify(y)} <br/>
          <span>>> ${deepEqual(x, y)}</span>`;
};

// To print results in
const resultDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.result');

resultDivs[0].innerHTML = result(obj1, obj2);
resultDivs[1].innerHTML = result(obj3, obj4);
resultDivs[2].innerHTML = result(obj5, obj6);
resultDivs[3].innerHTML = result(obj7, obj8);
resultDivs[4].innerHTML = result(obj9, obj10);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

span {
  color: #a0a0a0;
}

.result {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="result">
</div>

<div class="result">
</div>

<div class="result">
</div>

<div class="result">
</div>

<div class="result">
</div>
```