# Why is JavaScript code executed while condition is false? (Eloquent JavaScript - Deep comparison)

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

Question (Eloquent JS 2nd Ed, Chapter 4, Exercise 4):

> Write a function, deepEqual, that takes two values and returns true
>   only if they are the same value or are objects with the same
>   properties whose values are also equal when compared with a recursive
>   call to deepEqual.

Test Cases:

```
var obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
var obj1 = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
console.log(deepEqual(obj,obj1));
```

Code:

```
var deepEqual = function (x, y) {
    if ((typeof x == "object" && x != null) && (typeof y == "object" && y != null)) {
        if (Object.keys(x).length != Object.keys(y).length)
          return false;

        for (var prop in x) {
          if (y.hasOwnProperty(prop)){  
            if (! deepEqual(x[prop], y[prop])) //should not enter!!
                return false;
                alert('test');
          }else return false; // What does this section do?
        }
        return true;
    }
    else if (x !== y)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
};
```

Originaly fulfilled by [Paul Roub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25456134/4831589)

**Main question**: I  just added *alert* to the block of code after `if (! deepEqual(x[prop], y[prop]))` statement like kind of debugging, and now I have no idea why code inside is still executed while the statement itself is supposed to return `true` and `!` turns it `false`..?
*In addition:* What is `}else return false;` for? (same statement) The function seems to work fine without this section..

Comment: this is exactly the reason why you should never omit  the "{}" in if statements ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You added the `alert()` in such a way that it only runs when the `if` test *fails*, because you didn't add `{ }` to match the intention indicated by your indentation. If the `if` test succeeds, then the following `return` statement will exit the function and the `alert()` won't happen.

Any code that involves an `if` or `else if` block that always returns but is nevertheless followed by an `else` clause is a code smell. Either the `else` or the `return` is redundant; it's a matter of style which way you go.

That code is also flawed in that it tests the number of properties with `Object.keys()` — which implicitly only looks at "own" properties — but then uses a `for ... in` to loop through `x` *without* a `.hasOwnProperty()` check. (Whether inherited properties should affect the concept of "equality" is subjective, but it should probably be symmetric at least.)

Oh, and that first `else return false` clause after the check to see if `y` has one of the properties in `x` is just a quick exit. If `y` doesn't have a property name that's in `x`, then they can't be equal.

Finally note that any sort of "deep" equality tester that intends to be generic really needs to deal with object graph cycles and other even weirder things. (What of something in the object graph of `x` refers to part of `y`, and vice versa?) Deep object comparison is not a trivial thing.