# Two immutable lists - how to make triple equality work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, redux, immutable.js

Let's say we have an immutable object that is created using Facebook's great [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/). I want to compare two lists that were produced using `.map` or `.filter` out of single source and make sure they are equal. It seems to me, that when using map/filter you are creating a new object that has nothing to do with a previous object. How can I make triple equality `===` work? Does it make sense at all?

```
var list = Immutable.List([ 1, 2, 3 ]);
var list1 = list.map(function(item) { return item; })
var list2 = list.map(function(item) { return item; })

console.log("LIST1 =", list1.toJS())      // [1, 2, 3]
console.log("LIST2 =", list2.toJS())      // [1, 2, 3]
console.log("EQUAL ===?", list1===list2); // false! Why? How?
```

You can play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/eo4v1npf/1/

### Context

I am building application using React + Redux. My state has one list that contains items, that have attribute `selected`:

```
items: [
    {id: 1, selected: true},
    {id: 2, selected: false},
    {id: 3, selected: false},
    {id: 4, selected: true}
]
```

I want to pass only **selected ids** to another container, so I tried it using simple `connect`:

```
function getSelectedIds(items) {
    return items
        .filter((item) => item.get("selected"))
        .map((item) =>  item.get("id"));
}

export default connect(
    (state: any) => ({
        ids: getSelectedIds(state.get("items"))
})
)(SomePlainComponent);
```

Problem is, if I set additional attributes:

```
{id: 1, selected: true, note: "The force is strong with this one"}
```

This causes state to change and `SomePlainComponent` to rerender, although the list of selected Ids is *exactly* the same. How do I make sure pure renderer works?

### Edit with some additional info

For react pure rendering I was using mixin from [react-pure-render](https://github.com/gaearon/react-pure-render):

```
export default function shouldPureComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return !shallowEqual(this.props, nextProps) ||
           !shallowEqual(this.state, nextState);
}
```

As it is not aware of props that could be immutable, they are treated as changed, i.e.

```
this.props = {
    ids: ImmutableList1
}

nextProps = {
    ids: ImmutableList2
}
```

Although both attributes `ids` are equal by content, they are completely different objects and do not pass `ImmutableList1 === ImmutableList2` test and `shouldComponentUpdate` returns `true`. @Gavriel correctly pointed that deep equal would help, but that should be the last resort.

Anyway, I'll just apply accepted solution and problem will be solved, thanks guys! ;)

Comment: Why not using deepEqual: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456013/javascript-deepequal-comparison

Comment: Are you sure it gets rerendered? React works the way that when one single item in a state changes the whole new state gets compared with the whole old state. Therefore the state has been looped and you might receive some logs if you log something within that lifecycle. But if nothing DOM relevant has changed then react most likely won't rerender anything. Check the shouldComponentUpdate method.

Comment: Because the data is immutable..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can never have strict equality of immutable structures since an Immutable.js object, inherently, is unique.

You can use the `.is` function which takes two immutable objects and compares the values within them. This works because Immutable structures implement `equals` and `hashCode`.

```
var map1 = Immutable.Map({a:1, b:1, c:1});
var map2 = Immutable.Map({a:1, b:1, c:1});
console.log(Immutable.is(map1, map2));
// true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your component pure and working with `===` then you can also denormalize your Redux state and store the selectedIds as a property in the store.  Only update this list when an action occurs that adds/removes a selected item or toggles an item selection, but not when other arbitrary properties of the item are updated.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, but then my state would be stored in two places and I would have to synchronize it, using ... actions? State would look like:
`{ selectedItems: [1], items: [ {id: 1, selected: true}, {id: 2, selected: false} ]}`

After making state like that when handling select action I would need to update two state attributes, sounds easy, but I would have to do that **all the time**: when I delete an item, when I switch to next page, etc.

This would cause a lot of extra logic all around the code :)

Comment: Indeed, each reducer that you have that currently modifies the `items` property will also need to modify the `selectedItems` property if the action caused a change in the selection.  Presumably you only have a handful of actions that are affected?  A second option is to *remove the selected property* from the items and *only* store the selectedItems as a separate property in the store, either as a list or as a set: `{ selectedIds: [1,...], items: [{id:1, name:"foo"},...]}` or `{selectedIdSet: Set(1,...), items:{id:1,name:"foo"},...]}`