# Comparison 2 objects if property is undefined

Tags: javascript

```js
"use strict";
let obj1 = {
    key: undefined
};

let obj2 = {
    key: Symbol('')
};

// THIS SHOULD RETURN false
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2)); // true
```

I've read [the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), they said: there is another way to compare 2 objects like that case exactly by using [the replacer parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter). Just like:

```
let replacer = function (key, value) {
    if (value === undefined) {
        // do stuff...
    } else if (value['__proto__'].constructor.name === 'Symbol') {
        // do stuff...
    } else {
        // do stuff...
    }

    return value;
};
```

My question: is there another way that faster than using `replacer` like I just mention? I don't want to use that way cause of handling many things.

For example: if I have 20 functions like: `Symbol1()`, `Symbol2()`, `Symbol3()`... `Symbol20()`, I would re-use `if-else` statements many times.

Comment: You don't have to involve `JSON.stringify`, right? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456013/javascript-deepequal-comparison for example.

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.stringify` in the first place?

Comment: btw i ran your code and both structure resolves into `{}` thats why it is returning true.

Comment: @Blender I use `JSON.stringify` for 2 objects but I'm not sure some property is `undefined` or `Symbol('')`. It's just a case.

Comment: Is your goal to stringify an object or to compare two objects?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Convert 2 objects to strings via `JSON.stringify` before comparing is the fastest way that I've search on Google. But in this case I've showed, the result was wrong.

Comment: @SamuelToh ya. It's written in the doc. I've read.

Comment: Using `JSON.stringify` is probably not quite a good idea unless you can guarantee that there is no cyclic reference within the structure. Otherwise you might get hit by error `Converting circular structure to JSON` while stringify'ing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, just see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol):

> **Description**
>   To create a new primitive symbol, you write `Symbol()` with an optional string as its description:
>
> ```
> var sym1 = Symbol();
> var sym2 = Symbol("foo");
> var sym3 = Symbol("foo");
> ```
>
> The above code creates three new symbols. **Note that Symbol("foo") does
>   not coerce the string "foo" into a symbol.** It creates a new symbol
>   each time:

> **Symbols and JSON.stringify()**
>
> Symbol-keyed properties will be completely ignored when using
>   JSON.stringify():
>
> ```
> JSON.stringify({[Symbol("foo")]: "foo"});                 
> // '{}'
> ```

Unlike conventional objects., your `Symbol('AnyTextHere')` won't return any text so that `JSON.stringify` could convert it into one. Nothing is being returned and so `JSON.Stringify` returns empty String for both the cases and so your answer is `true` everytime.

---

**EDIT**

*Coming to your question*, the `Symbol()` will always return a new symbol everytime, and so NO TWO SYMBOLS WILL BE EVER SAME, EVEN IF YOU PASS SAME PARAMETER.

And so I think there's no need to compare the entire Object, just compare the key with `Symbol()`

```js
"use strict";
let obj1 = {
    key: undefined
};

let obj2 = {
    key: Symbol('')
};

let obj3 = {
    key: Symbol('')
};

// THIS SHOULD RETURN false
console.log(obj1.key === obj2.key); 
// false because Symbol() doesn't match undefined

console.log(obj2.key === obj2.key); 
// true because obj2.key is being compared with self

console.log(obj2.key === obj3.key); 
// false - NOTE that although the structure of obj2 and obj3 are same (COPIED AND PASTED)
// but since NO two Symbol() are same, and so the result is false
```

Comment: Many thanks! I understand you mean. And... what is your idea about comparing `obj1` and `obj2` in this case? Creating a new function and not using `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: @HappyCoding I've updated my answer for that... please see the edited answer.

Comment: Something like defining 2 instances of same class. They're same but similar to. That's help. Thanks!