# How do I check if an object contains an object without using methods?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if an object contains another object inside it with a partial match style.

So the following example should find the object `{'a':{'b':'c'}` twice in `myArray` once it works. Note that even though the `myArray[0]` object has an additional property of `'e': 'f'` on top of `{'a':{'b':'c'}` it still should be considered to contain `{'a':{'b':'c'}`.

I want to avoid using any methods such as reduce or map.

```js
const myArray = [
  {
    'a': {
      'b': 'c',
      'e': 'f',
    }
  },
    {
    'a': {
      'b': 'c'
    }
  },
    {
    'd': {
      'e': 'f'
    }
  },
]

function contains(array, index, object) {
  if () { // implementation???
    return true
  } 
  else {
    return false
  }
}

function quantityOfObjectInArray(object, array) {  
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
    if ( contains(array, i, object) ) {
     count++;
    }
  }
  return count
}

var quantity = quantityOfObjectInArray({'a':{'b':'c'}}, myArray) 
console.log(quantity) // expect: 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - deepEqual Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456013/javascript-deepequal-comparison)

Comment: This is about whether an object contains another object partially, not if they are equal

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries` to compare an object recursively:

```
function has(obj, proto) {
  for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(proto)) {
    if(typeof value === "object") {
      if(!obj[key] || !has(obj[key], value))
         return false;
    } else if(obj[key] !== value) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I'll need this if there's no alternative, but I'm trying to do it without methods like that, so I can see how it might actually be done the hard way first before using shortcuts like methods