# Object equality check when strings turn into numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to compare 2 objects. The difference between them is initially numbers are stored as strings and then when the form loads the form validators turn them into numbers.

Original object

```
{
  firstNumber: "1",
  secondNumber: "2"
}
```

Once loaded

```
{
  firstNumber: 1,
  secondNumber: 2
}
```

I have tried `angular.equals` but because their types aren't equal (`===`), function returns false.
`JSON.stringify`ing doesn't help either. The object can become quite big. I simply want to detect any changes made on the form but can't because it always tells me the form has changed. Is there a function that would take the above into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

Using non-strict equality.

One using lodash isEqualWith: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqualWith
and
modified to use non-strict equals: [Javascript - deepEqual Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456013/javascript-deepequal-comparison/25456134)

It may be safer to check if you have two primitives using typeof before checking.  There are faster deepEquals implementations.  You can just modify them to not use strict equals, or use typeof checks and then explicitly convert them to number or string for comparison.

```js
data1={
  firstNumber: "1",
  secondNumber: "2"
}


data2={
  firstNumber: 1,
  secondNumber: 2
}

console.log(
_.isEqualWith(data1,data2,(x,y)=>typeof x==="object"&&typeof y==="object"?undefined:x==y)
)

var deepEqual = function (x, y) {
  if (x == y) {
    return true;
  }
  else if ((typeof x == "object" && x != null) && (typeof y == "object" && y != null)) {
    if (Object.keys(x).length != Object.keys(y).length)
      return false;

    for (var prop in x) {
      if (y.hasOwnProperty(prop))
      {  
        if (! deepEqual(x[prop], y[prop]))
          return false;
      }
      else
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
  else 
    return false;
}

console.log(
deepEqual(data1,data2)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```