# Why doesn't the deepEqual method work on this code?

Tags: javascript, console.log, deepequals

I was looking at codes on stack overflow and I bumped into a problem that included this piece of code:

```
var obj = {here: 2};
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj));
// → true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: 1}));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: 2}));
// → true
console.log(obj === { here:2 });
// → false
```

I've tried to run this specific piece of code on my text editor, however the console displays:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: deepEqual is not defined
```

And it constantly happens when I use deepEqual on JavaScript, I'm still learning JavaScript, is there a reason as to why this is happening ? Isn't deepEqual supposed to be a JavaScript method ? Therefore able to run without being defined ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: There is no `deepEqual` function in JavaScript. If you want one, you have to write it yourself (or take it from somewhere).

Comment: If the error says it's not defined, it's not defined. There's no built in `deepEqual` function.

Comment: If the code you refer is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456013/javascript-deepequal-comparison/25456134), you can find the implementation of `deepEqual` from the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you !! I completely misunderstood it ! I thought it was a method and I was confused after googling it and not finding anything about it ! Thanks ! Sorry for bothering !