# How to type a function or object to receive propertis of same value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

So, I want to have some posibility to provide type assistance, when I have some function calls like in example below. I want to check if first and second argument has same value.

```js
myfn(12333, 12333); // To be OK
myfn(12333, 222); // To FAIL
```

```js
myfn({
  val_1: 12333,
  val_2: 12333,
}); // To be OK

myfn({
  val_1: 12333,
  val_2: 222,
}); // To FAIL
```

For some small amount of values, ("error", "warning", ...etc), I can make an override, but for numbers it's makes no sense.

Comment: In your first code block, the function has two parameters but in the second one it takes just one object with two properties. Is that intentional?

Comment: What's the point of this function?

Comment: @kelly I'm just asking about posibility to achieve this. Generic `fn<T>(T, T)` just checks type to be the same. But how about values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - deepEqual Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456013/javascript-deepequal-comparison)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you could type it. The Narrow-Type infers the value of your arguments.
By using two generics you prevent the widening for T from {a:12,b:23} to 12|23

```
export type Narrowable = string | number | bigint | boolean;
export type Narrow<A> =
    | (A extends Narrowable ? A : never)
    | (A extends [] ? [] : never)
    | {
        [K in keyof A]: A[K] extends Function ? A[K] : Narrow<A[K]>;
    };

declare function myfn<T,U extends T>(a: Narrow<T>, b: U): any
declare function myfn<T,U extends T>(a: Narrow<{ val_1: T, val_2: U }>): any
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't think it was possible, but it works. Together with this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59906630/3654943), finaly I can generate interesting things.
```typescript
function table<T, U extends T>(
  arr1: FixedArray<number, Narrow<T>>,
  arr2: FixedArray<number, U>,
): void {}
```